# Push notification not working after transferring to HTTPS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, push-notification, socket.io

Im working on how to run my push notification on my newly secured tomcat server. My notification runs on nodejs and socket.io module. It was working fine before transferring to HTTPS. Now it throws errors on console that said :

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com/home.jsp#' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://example.com:8002/socket.io/socket.io.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

and

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
at home.jsp:812
```

Here is the part my node js script w/c declares variables:

```
var sys = require('sys');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
sys.puts(stdout);
sys.puts(error);
}
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = require("nodemailer-smtp-transport");
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
fs = require('fs'),
mysql = require('mysql'),
connectionsArray = [],
connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: '127.0.0.1',
user: 'sampleUser',
password: 'samplePassword',
database: 'sampleDB',
port: 3306
}),
POLLING_INTERVAL = 2000,
pollingTimer;  
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
host : "smtp.gmail.com",
secureConnection : false,
port: 587,
auth : {
    user : "sample@email.com",
    pass : "sampleEmailPass"
}
}));
```

And this is my jsp file:

```
<html>
<head>
<!-- 
 * Author:      Gianluca Guarini
 * Contact:     gianluca.guarini@gmail.com
 * Website:     http://www.gianlucaguarini.com/
 * Twitter:     @gianlucaguarini
-->
    <title>Push notification server streaming on a MySQL db</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <time></time>
    <div id="container"></div>
<script src="http://example.com:8002/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

    // create a new websocket
    var socket = io.connect('http://example.com:8002');
    // on message received we print all the data inside the #container div
    socket.on('notification', function (data) {
    var usersList = "";

    $.each(data.users,function(index,user){
        if (user.num_count!=0) {
            if(<%=session.getAttribute("accessID")%>==user.user_login_id)
        {

        usersList += user.num_count;
        }
    }
    });

    if ($('#container').text() < usersList)
    {
      var diff = usersList-$('#container').text();
      notifyMe(usersList);
      /*
      for(var e =0; e<diff; e++)
      {

      notifyMe(diff);
      }*/
    }

   $('#container').html(usersList);

   // $('time').html('Last Update:' + data.time);
  });
  function notifyMe(usersList) {
  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
   var options = {
    icon: '/icon/main_page/main_icon.png',
    sound: '/icon/sounds/Water_DROP.mp3'
  }
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
  alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
return false;
  }

  // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
  // If it's okay let's create a notification
   var notification = new Notification('You have '+usersList+' item(s) for approval',options);

  notification.sound;
   }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
  Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
  // If the user accepts, let's create a notification
  if (permission === "granted") {
    var notification = new Notification('You have '+usersList+' item(s) for approval',options);

  notification.sound;
  }
  });
  }
  notification.onclick = function(){
  window.focus();
  };
   // At last, if the user has denied notifications, and you 
    // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
    }   
</script>
</body>
```

What I've done so far was translate all http to https. It solved the mixed type errors but not the undefined io situation. I've search some topics but it uses express.js and it needs a key and certificate.

TIA

Comment: It still says `http://` in the code you have shown us in several places. Have you checked whether those resources still loaded properly, after you made those changes? Have you verified that all of those support HTTPS to begin with?

Comment: Yes, i tried to translate all http tags to https. But it only solved the mixed type errors.

Comment: And this “Yes” is supposed to be the answer to everything I just asked you above? Like whatever you(?) have set up at `example.com:8002` is supposed to just automatically handle HTTPS instead of HTTP now, although as we know HTTP and HTTPS usually use different ports to begin with?

Comment: oh sorry, I've forgot to add on the node js file that I have set my app to listen on port 8002. 
I have a line like this on the js file:
`app.listen(8002);`

Comment: And you modified `var app = require('http').createServer(handler)` as well?

Comment: Yes sir CBroe, like every tag of http ive replaced it with https. make and both the app and client to listen on port:8002. Ive even used my public ip to replace my domain name.

Comment: So then you can call `https://example.com:8002/socket.io/socket.io.js` directly via your browser address bar, and it shows the file fine without any errors or warning regarding HTTPS/SSL or anything else? (Check browser console, too.)

Answer (score -1):

Very easy solution.
Just change your "socket.io.js" script to be serve over https and not http protocol.
For example:
'https://yoursite.com/socket.io.js' and not 'http://yoursite.com/socket.io.js'

Comment: And the first error message has gone? Or still happens?